# Does my graphics card support CUDA?

Tags: 17.10, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I am running Ubuntu 17.10, and this is my graphics card:

[image: screenshot]
[image]

and I want to know if it is CUDA enabled. There is a NVIDIA GEFORCE sticker on my computer, so I thought it might be...

Comment: from your screenshot, it seems you are using the embedded Intel graphics card, not the NVidia one. So you should probably fisrt have a look at optimus / prime to enable / disable the NVidia card.

Comment: @alci I changed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqDvq.png) option, would that be enough, or should I change something in bios?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the graphics hardware of your computer supports CUDA. However, it appears that the dedicated Nvidia graphics adapter is currently inactive in favour of the integrated Intel graphics.

As a first step you need to ensure that the [Nvidia graphics drivers are installed](/q/61396/175814).